# How to implement equation for calculate image dimensions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, equation, algebra

Calculate image dimensions (image renderer) and the math checks out but i'm really stuck on how to actually implement it in code...

The equation system:

I. 2x + y = 1287 (viewport width)

II. 4/3x - 3/4y = 0

How would you go about implementing this in code? Pointing me in the right direction is appreciated as well, indeed!

Thanks in advance, have a good day!

Comment: What is x and what is y? Is it actually x and y pixel dimensions?

Comment: Yes, pixel dimension, X being the width of a potential profile image, while Y would be the width of a landscape image. Here, we take 2 of X because one row of images would have 2 profile oriented images.
And as we know the image aspect ratios (4/3, 3/4), we can later calculate the heights of either images.

Comment: So how do you solve a Math question?

Comment: I can solve this on paper, but how exaclty do I multiply a variable with no value and then subtrackt another one from it? It gotta be me, yes, it most definately just me being bad at math, but I'm still not closer... If you know it so good, how hard can it be to show an example? Really... I'm not trying to insult or annoy you, but you're wasting both of us' time and energy

Comment: Whenever you will have a problem solving a math formula again: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%7B2x+%2B+y+%3D+v%2C+4%2F3x+-+3%2F4y+%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%7D%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat the computer like a calculator. Because that's what it literally is, only more fancy.

Do exactly what you would do to solve the equations with a calculator. Do not use mental arithmetics to solve the equations.

Using a calculator, it is not possible to solve the equations as is. Because that's not how a calculator works. Instead, if you use a calculator you would need to rearrange the calculations so that you can input numbers into the calculator - again DO NOT CHEAT AND USE MENTAL ARITHMETICS.

So, the first equation gives us two functions (in the mathematical sense) that we can calculate with a calculator:

```
1a: x = (1287 - y) / 2
1b: y = 1287 - 2x
```

You now can literally treat the equations above as code depending on weather you have x or y as input:

```
function getX (y) {
    return (1287 - y) / 2
}

function getY (x) {
    return 1287 - (2 * x)
}
```

The second equation is a bit confusing. The width to height ratio of the portrait picture is 3:4 and the landscape picture is just rotated. **What this means is that the ratio of the width of the landscape picture to the width of the portrait picture is also simply 4:3** (NOTE: At this point of writing this answer I didn't realise that your second equation describes a different layout which I explore below.. continue reading to get the functions you are looking for. However, I'll leave this part of the answer here because it illustrates how to convert mathematical equations into functions). This gives us:

```
2a: x = 3y/4
2b: y = 4x/3
```

Again giving us:

```
function getX (y) {
    return y * 3 / 4
}

function getY (x) {
    return x * 4 / 3
}
```

You mention:

> one row of images would have 2 profile oriented images (and one landscape)

Presumably you want to display your images as follows:

### Simple layout

```
 ┌─────┐ ┌─────┐
 │     │ │     │ ┌───────┐
 │     │ │     │ │       │
 │     │ │     │ └───────┘
 └─────┘ └─────┘
 ┌─────┐           ┌─────┐
 │     │ ┌───────┐ │     │
 │     │ │       │ │     │
 │     │ └───────┘ │     │
 └─────┘           └─────┘
```

or

```
 ┌─────┐ ┌─────┐ ┌───────┐
 │     │ │     │ │       │
 │     │ │     │ └───────┘
 │     │ │     │
 └─────┘ └─────┘
 ┌─────┐ ┌───────┐ ┌─────┐
 │     │ │       │ │     │
 │     │ └───────┘ │     │
 │     │           │     │
 └─────┘           └─────┘
```

The calculations for this is rather straightforward. If you are using a fixed-width display of 1287 pixels you don't even need a computer. You can simply solve this with pen and paper since the result will be constant:

```
x = (1287 - y) / 2
```

and

```
y = 4x / 3
```

Solving it by substituting for `y`:

```
x = (1287 - (4x / 3)) / 2

2x = 1287 - (4x / 3)

6x = 3861 - 4x

6x + 4x = 3861

10x = 3861

x = 386.1
```

Giving us:

```
y = 514.8
```

Double checking `514.8 + 386.1 + 386.1 = 1287`. We can conveniently round the numbers to get nice integer pixel values: `386 + 386 + 515 = 1287`.

So in your code you can simply write:

```
const x = 386;
const y = 515;
```

However, if you want the width to be variable then the first equation wouldn't have a fixed value of `1287`. Instead you would write it as:

```
x = (viewport_width - y) / 2
```

Again, substituting for `y` gives us:

```
x = (viewport_width - (4x / 3)) / 2

2x = viewport_width - (4x / 3)

6x = (3 * viewport_width) - 4x

10x = viewport_width * 3

x = viewport_width * 3 / 10
```

Giving us two functions:

```
function portraitWidth (viewport_width) {
    return viewport_width * 3 / 10;
}

function landscapeWidth (viewport_width) {
    return portraitWidth(viewport_width) * 4 / 3; // y = 4x/3
}
```

Of course, you can easily rewrite the above to give rounded integer values:

```
function portraitWidth (viewport_width) {
    let x = viewport_width * 3 / 10;
    return Math.round(x);
}

function landscapeWidth (viewport_width) {
    let y = portraitWidth(viewport_width) * 4 / 3;
    return Math.round(y);
}
```

In hindsight, given how simple these functions turn out to be we probably should have derived them first before doing the fixed 1287 pixel calculations.

### Complicated layout

If however you intend to display your images as follows it gets a bit more complicated:

```
 ┌─────┐ ┌─────┐ ┌────────────┐
 │     │ │     │ │            │
 │     │ │     │ │            │
 │     │ │     │ │            │
 └─────┘ └─────┘ └────────────┘
 ┌─────┐ ┌────────────┐ ┌─────┐
 │     │ │            │ │     │
 │     │ │            │ │     │
 │     │ │            │ │     │
 └─────┘ └────────────┘ └─────┘
```

This makes the relationship in part 2 not quite as straightforward. The height of the profile picture is the same as the height of the landscape picture. We know the width to height ratio of the portrait picture is 3/4. But this means that the relationship between the width of the landscape and profile pictures is not as simple as 4:3.

Instead the relationship is a bit indirect. The height of the portrait picture is the same as the height of the landscape picture:

```
hx = hy
```

Given that `x:hx = 3:4` and `y:hy = 4:3` we get:

```
x = 3 * hx / 4
```

and

```
hy = 3 * y / 4
```

Substituting `hx` for `hy` because they are equal:

```
x = 3 * (3y / 4) / 4

4x = 9y / 4

x = 9 * y / 16
```

or

```
y = 16 * x / 9
```

Going back to the original equation for layout:

```
x = (viewport_width - y) / 2
```

Again, substituting for `y` gives us:

```
x = (viewport_width - (16x / 9)) / 2

2x = viewport_width - (16x / 9)

18x = (9 * viewport_width) - 16x

18x + 16x = viewport_width * 9

x = viewport_width * 9 / 34
```

This gives us the following functions:

```
function portraitWidth (viewport_width) {
    return viewport_width * 9 / 34;
}

function landscapeWidth (viewport_width) {
    return portraitWidth(viewport_width) * 16 / 9;
}
```

Double checking by plugging in `1287` we get:

```
x = 340.68
y = 605.65
```

If you round them and add them up you get: `606 + 341 + 341 = 1288`. Off by one pixel but close enough for UI work. You can always reduce the width of the landscape by one pixel if the result is off by one pixel.

Note that by the time I finished writing my complete answer I didn't realise that the two functions above are an implementation of your second equation. If we plug in the two values for x and y above we will indeed satisfy your second equation. Thanks to @audzzy for pointing out that your second equation gives y:x ratio of 16:9:

```
(4/3) * 340.68 - (3/4) * 605.65 ≈ 0
```

Comment: something's off in the first assignment you did: ((4/3)*386.1)-((3/4)*514.8) = 128.7 , not 0..
thats because y=(16/9)x not  y = 4x / 3

Comment: @audzzy As I mentioned at length in my answer the 4/3x - 3/4y = 0  relationship is wrong. Instead the relationship is just 4x - 3y = 0. Read the problem statement, not the equation. The problem is he is arranging two portraits and one landscape in a row

Comment: @audzzy Maybe I should have highlighted that logic. I'll bold it in the answer

Comment: @audzzy Hmm it looks like the `4x/3 - 3y/4 = 0` equation is valid for the second (complicated layout) case. I didn't realise that until I noticed the 16/9 ratio in your comment which is the same as the expression I derived for the second set of functions. ((4/3)*340.68)-((3/4)*605.65) does indeed get very close to 0. So the actual answer the OP was looking for is the second set of functions. I'll remove the `not 4/3x....` part in my answer

Comment: Wow... thank you so much!! Yes, the complicated layout is what I was looking for, sorry for the misleading explanation. I really really appreciate your answer, have a great day! :)

Comment: I've just converted the formula to having two landscape and one portrait images using your answer! Works perfect, can't thank enough.

Comment: @leventecsoba Yup. Sorry for the long rambling answer. I didn't quite know where the reasoning would take me when I started to write it. Now that I think about it I could have written a much shorter answer by simply saying that you need to convert equations to (math) functions and from there it's much simpler to convert it to code

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
let viewport = 1287;
let y = (8/17) * viewport;
let x = (viewport - y) / 2;
```

which would give you these values:

```
viewport = 1287, 
x = 340.6764705882353, 
y = 605.6470588235294
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers

Comment: Yes, I would want to get the values of X and Y, as in solving the equation system. That's all I'm trying to figure out, how do I solve or implement this system of equations in javascript.

Comment: Strange looking JavaScript

Comment: That looks like... C#?

Comment: sorry, I was looking at a c# question before so I was still under the impression.. fixed it to js...